# Reverse of a strictly increasing function also strictly increasing?

Tags: calculus

I have $\,y=f\left(x\right)\,$ and $\,\dfrac{d\hspace{0.2ex}f(x)}{d\hspace{0.1ex}x}>0,\;$ $\,f\left(x\right)\,$ continuous.

Can I conclude that $\;\dfrac{d\hspace{0.1ex}x\left(y\right)}{d\hspace{0.1ex}y}>0$?

I.e. the reverse $x\left(y\right)$ is also a strictly increasing function of $y$?

Comment: Yes by the [Inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) as long as $\frac{dy}{dx}\ne0$ which it isn't in your case.

Comment: If $f$ is **continuously differentiable** (i.e. $f'$ itself is continous) you can apply the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: Great, thanks guys!

Comment: Do you know any literature where I can find this theorem? Google doenst give me any books if I search for "inverse function theorem"...